# Iterative slurm job

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch

I'm trying to optimize a study I'm doing. I currently have to job scripts I call them step1 and step2. In step1

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00

module load <everything I need>



echo "Start of program at `date`"

srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable1 ../data/my_datafile0.dat

echo "End of program at `date`"
```

After this job is done I have a new datafile that we can call my_datafile1.dat and this goes into the the second job script step2:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00

module load <everything I need>



echo "Start of program at `date`"

srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable1 ../data/my_datafile1.dat

echo "End of program at `date`"
```

After this job I have a new datafile called my_datafile2.dat which I use in step1 again and then the new one in step2 etc. I'm wondering if there is a way to write a job script which does this iteration for me. I would like to tell it to do 20 iterations and then I'll end up with my_datafile1.dat, my_datafile2.dat, ..., my_datafile20.dat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single job? If so, you could just use a loop, like follows (with a bit of verbosity in the inner loop, but can be replace by a single line if wanted).

Edit after the clarification in the comments below: Basically one step is an execution of `my_executable1` followed by `my_executable2`. To simplify, let's call `A` the output of `1` and `B` the output of `2`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00

module load <everything I need>

echo "Start of program at `date`"

for I in $(seq 10); do
  CMD="srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable1 ../data/my_datafile_A_${I}.dat"
  echo "Launching command \"$CMD\" at $(date)"
  eval $CMD
  CMD="srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable2 ../data/my_datafile_B_${I}.dat"
  echo "Launching command \"$CMD\" at $(date)"
  eval $CMD
done

echo "End of program at `date`"
```

If for some reason you *really* want to increment the index at each substep, you can use `bc` for the small computation:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00

module load <everything I need>

echo "Start of program at `date`"

for I in $(seq 10); do
  INDEX=$(echo "2*$I-1" | bc)
  CMD="srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable1 ../data/my_datafile_${INDEX}.dat"
  echo "Launching command \"$CMD\" at $(date)"
  eval $CMD
  INDEX=$(echo "2*$I" | bc)
  CMD="srun $HOME/project/bin/my_executable2 ../data/my_datafile_${INDEX}.dat"
  echo "Launching command \"$CMD\" at $(date)"
  eval $CMD
done

echo "End of program at `date`"
```

Comment: Thank you @keldorn how do I include executable2 such that what is evaluated in executable1 is used in executable2 which is then used in executable1 and so on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I thought you wanted to run `my_executable1` 20 times, with the output of the previous step each time. Do you want steps 1, 1-2, 1-2-3, 1-2-3-4, etc.? Or something else?

Comment: No it's a two step iterative process. First a datafile is produced with executable1 called datafile1, then datafile1 is used for executable2 to create datafile2 which is used for executable1 to create datafile3 which is used for executable2 to produce datafile4 and so on, hope that makes sense?

Comment: So basically `my_executable1` and `my_executable2` should both be inside of the same loop iteration. I updated the answer accordingly. Please update the question to clarify your request.

Comment: Thanks, right now the datafiles are being named by the executable. Is there a way to name the files "datafile_B_${I}" etc within the job script?

Comment: Yes, see the first snippet I posted. Unless it is in your executables, I don't know what goes on in there. BTW, it would probably be better to have executables which accept input and output names as parameters, not the single parameter as now.